# Pandas: Fill na with mode of a group

Tags: python, pandas, mode, fillna

I have a `df` with multiple columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Store':['M1','M2','M3','M1','M1','M2','M2','M3','M3'],
                   'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                   'Price_Category':[np.nan,X,np.nan,np.nan,Y,Y,Z,np.nan,Z]})
```

How do I fill the `NaN` on `Price_Category` with the mode, based only on `Category`?

I tried to use:

```py
df['Price_Category'] = df.groupby('Category')['Price_Category'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
```

But I get this error: `KeyError: 0`

Other ways that I tried, started to fill the `NaN` with the name from the `Store`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for first value of `Series` by position:

```
f = lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iat[0])
df['Price_Category'] = df.groupby('Category')['Price_Category'].apply(f)

print (df)
  Store Category Price_Category
0    M1        A              X
1    M2        A              X
2    M3        A              X
3    M1        B              Y
4    M1        B              Y
5    M2        B              Y
6    M2        C              Z
7    M3        C              Z
8    M3        C              Z
```

If error:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

it means only NaNs one or more groups (changed data for raise error):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Store':['M1','M2','M3','M1','M1','M2','M2','M3','M3'],
                   'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                  'Price_Category':[np.nan,'X',np.nan,np.nan,'Y','Y',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

---

```
#test if at least one non NaN else return same values (NaNs)
f = lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iat[0]) if x.notna().any() else x
df['Price_Category'] = df.groupby('Category')['Price_Category'].apply(f)

print (df)
  Store Category Price_Category
0    M1        A              X
1    M2        A              X
2    M3        A              X
3    M1        B              Y
4    M1        B              Y
5    M2        B              Y
6    M2        C            NaN
7    M3        C            NaN
8    M3        C            NaN
```

Comment: Still an error:

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho - Added solution to answer.